# Make dropdown menu floating in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, floating

I'm trying to create a quite complex navbar using bootstrap. I wonder wether it is possible to make the dropdown menu floating, so it does not make the navbar big and ugly. The picture is quite self-explanatory:

[image: Screenshot of what I want]

Code:

```css
.menu-item-seleccionado {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.menu-item-sin-seleccionar {
  color: white !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.titulo-menu {
  margin-left: 1%;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-light bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0; width: 100%;">

    <div class="flex-izquierda">
      <a class="navbar-brand titulo-menu" href="inicio.html">Resano Innovación</a>
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler bg-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#bar"
      aria-controls="bar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="flex-derecha collapse navbar-collapse" id="bar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" style="margin: 0 !important; ">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active rounded menu-item-seleccionado" aria-current="page" href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menu-item-sin-seleccionar" href="ubicacion.html">Ubicación</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menu-item-sin-seleccionar" href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menu-item-sin-seleccionar" href="certificado.html">Certificado de calidad</a></li>

        <!-- Imagen para cambiar el idioma -->
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-brand" href="../en/inicio.html">
          <img src="../img/eng.png" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 40px; padding-left: 10px;" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.menu-item-seleccionado {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.menu-item-sin-seleccionar {
  color: white !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.titulo-menu {
  margin-left: 1%;
  color: white !important;
}




@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
    flex-basis: auto;
}
.flex-derecha {
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    background: black;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
}
.collapse:not(.show) {
    display: none !important;
}
.nav-item
{
   width:250px;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-light bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0; width: 100%;">

    <div class="flex-izquierda">
      <a class="navbar-brand titulo-menu" href="inicio.html">Resano Innovación</a>
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler bg-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#bar"
      aria-controls="bar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="flex-derecha collapse navbar-collapse" id="bar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" style="margin: 0 !important; ">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active rounded menu-item-seleccionado" aria-current="page" href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menu-item-sin-seleccionar" href="ubicacion.html">Ubicación</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menu-item-sin-seleccionar" href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menu-item-sin-seleccionar" href="certificado.html">Certificado de calidad</a></li>

        <!-- Imagen para cambiar el idioma -->
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-brand" href="../en/inicio.html">
          <img src="../img/eng.png" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 40px; padding-left: 10px;" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: have you no css formatting decency?